# I made a lost in tax year 16/17 on DFT, can I claim it against it for self assessment in 17/18?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, trading, self-assessment

If I made a small loss in trading stocks DFT/CFD's in 16/17, could I use it in my self assessment tax return to reduce the tax I pay in 17/18?

Comment: Depends are you paying any CGT tax this year? you cant use losses like these to reduce your income tax if that was what you are thinking

Comment: None unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Trading CFDs is [subject to capital gains tax](https://moneyterms.co.uk/cfd/cfd-tax/) rather than income tax. If you make a loss, you can only set it off against any other capital gains, but not your income.

However, you can also carry the loss forward in case you make a gain above the CGT threshold in the future: https://www.gov.uk/capital-gains-tax/losses